# Count occurrences of letters in a word to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with words in the first column. I want to create columns in the same dataframe with number of occurrences of each letter in each word.

The dataframe should look something like:

```
Word    A    B    C    D    E  ...  
BED     0    1    0    1    1
```

Is there an easy way to do this and update it for new words added to the dataframe? It should create a column for the letter if it doesn't exist

I've tried this -

```
for i in range(len(df)):
   u = df.iat[i, 0]
   for j in u:
      df.iat[i, j] = u.count(j)
```

Doesn't work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) in a list comprehension then reindex using [`string.ascii_uppercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase):

```
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_uppercase

df = df[['Word']].join(pd.DataFrame([Counter(word) for word in df['Word'].str.upper()])
                       .reindex(list(ascii_uppercase), axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int))
```

[output]

```
print(df)

  Word  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  ...  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z
0  BED  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  ...  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

[1 rows x 27 columns]
```